# Converting String value date into Date using simple date format in android

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, date-conversion

I have a string variable which contains date and time in the following format

EDIT:

```
String newdate="Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05:30 2014";
```

I need to covert and parse it into this date format using simpledateformat as below:

```
Date nd=04-03-2014 16:58:00
```

But I don't know the string pattern for converting using simpledateformat.

I have given as

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss");
```

But it gave me wrong output.

Is the string pattern for simpledateformat sdf correct? If I'm wrong can someone please correct me in converting newdate to date nd format.

Comment: Is it sooo dificuilt to run a simple search on that really popular topic? See the **Related** answers to the right >>>>

Comment: @injecteer didn't find answer to what I need. So I posted here. Can you please help me out. Tried many string patterns for simple date format, but still not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");`

But before conversion replace "**.**" on "**:**" in "GMT+05.30"

**Example:**

```
    String newdate="Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05:30 2014";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");

    try {
     Date d = sdf.parse(newdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your date string is not correct, which should be

```
String newdate="Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05:30 2014";
```

not this...

```
String newdate="Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05.30 2014";
```

you placed **Dot (.)** in  `GMT+05.30` instead of **Colon (:)** as `GMT+05:30`.

Now, Use this format...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

**For Exmaple:**

```
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

    try {
        date = formatter.parse(newdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(date);
    Log.i("ConvertedDate", convertedDate);
```

**OutPut:**

```
03-04 19:39:49.959: I/ConvertedDate(310): 04-03-2014 17:28
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is not correct.
Try:

```
"Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05:30 2014";
```

instead of:

`"Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05.30 2014";`

It seems that SimplaDateFormat this GMT+05:30 part works only with ':'.

Than you can parse it like that:

```
    String newdate="Tue Mar 04 16:58:00 GMT+05:30 2014";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" );
    Date  nd =  sdf.parse(newdate);
```